# a problem involving the sum of two complex functions with simple poles at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have two complex functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ which both have a simple pole at $z = 0$.  Furthermore, both are holomorphic elsewhere in $\mathbb{C}$.  I need to show the following:

$f(z) + g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ iff $\int_{C[0, 1]} f(z) dz = - \int_{C[0, 1]} g(z) dz$

Comment: Do you know what the residue of a function at a pole is?

Comment: What does $C[0,1]$ mean?

Comment: @copper.hat, circle of radius 1 centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

In the following $\gamma$ is unit circle around $z=0$.

If $f+g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, it is equal to a function that is analytic everywhere and hence $\int_\gamma (f+g) dz = 0$ from which one
direction follows.

If $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$ then it can be written as
$f(z) = {\phi(z) \over z}$, where $\phi(0) \neq 0$. Similarly,
$g(z) = {\gamma(z) \over z}$, where $\gamma(0) \neq 0$.

We have $\int_\gamma {\phi(z) \over z} dz = \phi(0)$ (look at the Laurent expansion, for example), and similarly
$\int_\gamma {\gamma(z) \over z} dz = \gamma(0)$.

Hence $\phi(0) +\gamma(0) = 0$ and so $f(z)+g(z) = \sum_{k \ge 1} (\phi^{(k)}(0) + \gamma^{(k)}(0)) z^{k-1}$, for $z \neq 0$, and since
the right hand side is analytic at $z=0$, it follows that $f+g$ has a
removable singularity at $z=0$.